# Retain dynamically entered text from jquery into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, text

Thanks to the fine folks here I was able to put together a working prototype of a previous issue I was having - that of using a textbox input with a password requirement to populate a  element.

Now, everything works as intended - however, I have noticed a quirk that I'm hoping someone can help me with. When entering a new value for the  my browser session will reflect that change, however, anyone else visiting this same page will be greeted with the initial value that has been set.

HTML Here:

```
<input id="txtBox" type="textbox" value="0" style="display:none;" />
<input id="txtBox2" type="textbox" value="0" style="display:none;" /> 
<input id="passwordBox" type="password" value="" style="display: none;" />
<div id="txtBoxValue" style="height: 25px; background: #e3e3e3; width: 100px;"></div>
<div id="txtBox2Value"></div>
```

Javascript Here:

```
$(function() {

   $('#txtBoxValue').on('click', function() {
       $(this).hide();
       $('#txtBox2Value').hide();
       $('#passwordBox').show().focus();
   });

   $('input#passwordBox').bind('keypress', function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
           if($(this).val() == 'password') {
               $(this).val('');
               $(this).hide();
               $('#txtBox').show().focus();
               $('#txtBox2').show();
           }
           else {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).hide();
            $('#txtBoxValue').show();
            $('#txtBox2Value').show();
           }

       }
   });

   $('#txtBox').bind('keypress', function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       var that = $(this);
       $('#txtBoxValue').text(that.val()).show();
       that.hide();
       }
   });

 $('#txtBox2').bind('keypress', function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       var that = $(this);
       $('#txtBox2Value').text(that.val()).show();
       that.hide();
       }
   });

});
```

You can view the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/curtisrichins/Q22tG/21/

How best would it be to retain the new  information so that its displayed for any visitors, as opposed to defaulting back to the original entry value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to store state on the server - there is no way to make a change available to all visitors otherwise. You don't state what server-side language you're using, but this state could be held in a database or similar.

So in terms of the client-side code, you would need to `POST` the data back to the server using an ajax request (or full page postback) to be able to store it. Then, in the client-side code, you would need to allow a `GET` of that data (again using ajax or similar).

Given that, your code would be updated with something vaguely similar to the following:

```
$(function () {

    //Load data from server 
    $.get("/yourserver/handler", function(data) {
        $('#passwordBox').val(data);
    });

    //Send data to server event handler
    $('#passwordBox').blur(function() {
        //Ajax POST to server
        $.post("/yourserverurl/handler", { valueToSave: $(this).val() });
    }).fail(function() { alert("Could not save to server"); });

    //All the other event handlers, etc that you had before
    //...
    //...
});
```

From the above, I showed using `blur` on the textbox to send data to the server, but that could be anything - click of a button or whatever.

Comment: That's what I thought the answer would be. Currently there is no server-side language being used - it was all being handled client-side. What recommendations would you have as far as where to start refactoring this to work the way I would like it to? Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Updated the answer which hopefully gives you a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I put some things together but it was becoming cost-productive, so I ended up porting the whole thing into a simple CMS that can handle updates.